# How to change icon of IconButton after pressed in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want the icon to change after the icon is pressed, but setState() is not working.
In addition, after refreshing the page with a temporary method, the icon changes.

I check if it is a favorite with checkItemInFav() .

```
void checkItemInFav(String ID, BuildContext context) {
    example.sharedPreferences
            .getStringList(example.userFavoritesList)
            .contains(ID)
        ? deleteItemToFav(id, context)
        : addItemToFav(id, context);
  }
```

I will go for checkFav() it will decide which IconButton to use.

```
bool checkFav(String id, BuildContext context) {
    List temp = example.sharedPreferences
        .getStringList(example.userFavoritesList);

    if(temp.isNotEmpty){
      for (int i = 0; i <= temp.length - 1; i++) {
        if (id == temp[i]) return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

The structure of the relevant part of my code.

```
Info(Model model, BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 1),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 150,
        width: width,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.network(""),
            SizedBox(width: 5.0),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(""),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(""),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                  
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: favorite.checkFav(model.id, context) == true
                        ? IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            iconSize: 15.0,
                            onPressed: () {
                              favorite.checkItemInFav(model.id, context);
                            },
                          )
                        : IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                            iconSize: 15.0,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            onPressed: () {
                              favorite.checkItemInFav(model.id, context);
                            },
                          ),
                  ),
                  //Divider(color: Colors.black38),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I make an instant icon change?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that before and after your fav function runs, the widget tree looks like: ... Column > Align > IconButton ...

Since it looks like there's no change (without delving into the actual state of the widgets), flutter will assume there's no state change to make (even if you call setState()). Your solution would be to add keys in the appropriate places. (You can play around by adding them to various places and see what effects they have, like the Row, the Column, the Align widget, maybe even all of them and see what it does.). Do refer to this video for more information of when and where to use keys in your Flutter app > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc